# for(i=center && j=center;i>=center && i<n- 1 && j>=center && j<n-1;i++ && j--)

Tags: java, for-loop

Please tell if I can give multiple condition in for loop. As in my above statement its giving an error as:

> for(i=center && j=center;i>=center && i=center && j ^
>
> 1 error:
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: /EightiesKids4.java:23: error: not a statement

Comment: Post your complete code.

Comment: You are greatly lacking some fundamental knowledge of the Java syntax. Go and learn it by yourself. We cannot do that for you. This is too broad.

Comment: The title of the question is not good !

Comment: Can you edit your post to add a proper title and format example code in code blocks?

Answer (score 3):

If `i` & `j` aren't already defined:

```
for(int i=center, j=center; // pre-condition
i >= center && i < n- 1 && j < n-1; // condition
i++, j--) // post-condition
```

Comment: We can assume that `center` is immutable in the scope of this loop. Isnt the `i>= center` redundant?

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
for(int i=center, j=center;i>=center && i<n- 1 && j>=center && j<n-1; i++, j--)
```

Comment: Its working. thank you Sir.